# How to add a file to fixtures folder in Cypress?

Tags: path, request, cypress, fixtures

In my Cypress e2e tests I need to work with lots of files (some of them are heavy). I cannot just add them manually to fixtures folder and to push them to git (it will use all repository space).

So I have a server for files to store. With Selenium I could just use an absolute network path to get an access to a file. As I understand, in Cypress I cannot use an absolute network path, I need to add a file to fixtures folder to work with it.

So how do I transfer files from my server to Cypress fixtures folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cy.request()` as replacement for `cy.fixture()`

```js
cy.fixture('path/to/fixture')
  .then(data => {
    ...
  })
```

to this

```js
cy.request('url/to/server/fixture')
  .then(response => {
    const data = response.json()       // may need to unpack the response
    ...
  })
```

---

#### Memory blowout with large fixtures

Beware of accessing large amounts of data with `cy.fixture()`.

See [Loaded just once](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Loaded-just-once)

> Please keep in mind that fixture files are assumed to be unchanged during the test, and thus Cypress loads them just once. Even if you overwrite the fixture file itself, the already loaded fixture data remains the same.

This means the fixture data is ***cached*** for the whole test run, and is not garbage-collected until Cypress exits, which might cause memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a command that gets the desired file by API and call this command in the before hook. For example:

Command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loadMyFixtures', (filePath) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `my/fixture/endpoint`,
        timeout: 10000
    }).then(res => {
        cy.writeFile(filePath, res.body);
        cy.log('Loaded from API');
        });
});
```

The before hook:

```
describe('my suit of tests', () => {
before(function() {
  cy.loadMyFixtures('path/to/my/downloaded/fixture')
})
```

Comment: So you mean, I just need to download files to fixtures folder, and then use them, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's what I do when the fixtures begin to be too big to be packaged in the application or when I want to use the same fixtures in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is within a folder under the fixtures folder, it may not work on V12.7.0. In that case, when I add a `wait` statement then it works for me. Like this:

```
describe('test', function() {
    before(function () {   
        cy.fixture('path/to/fixture')
        .then(function(data) {
           this.dta = data;
           cy.wait(1000);
         })
      })
  })
```